# Best way to get "into the security industry"?

Tags: certification, cissp, career

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the career paths in the computer security field?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/what-are-the-career-paths-in-the-computer-security-field)

I've been called a "jack of all trades" guy, who has been working in health care and finance for about seven years.  Most of my positions, including my current one of 3-4 years, has had a strong concentration in security.

I've been trying to find a niche to fit in professionally, and think that I am at a great disadvantage without one (specifically in NYC where I live and work).  Now I've heard the stigma of "no 'hacker' gets certs..." but I am curious, is this the best way to solidify my access to the security niche?  If so, should I aim for CCSP, CISSP (for which I can be sponsored to meet the requirements)?

I have experience, but I just don't think that's enough to actually secure a security engineer position (in the long run).  I also don't think a certification is a magic bullet, but I gotta start somewhere.  Does anyone have any other suggestions that could change the path of the rest of my life?