# Categories for Information Security Learning

Tags: audit

I'm learning Information Security, Actually I'm a software developer but for my work I need to learn a lot of Information Security, you know attacks and defenses, But I really don't know where to start, I would like to know if there is a list of categories or specific topics? I want to know just to arrive all the topics in order.

Thanks.

Comment: Try OWASP? This question is really too broad to answer. It's like asking "I want to learn how to be a software developer, where do I start?" The field is massive and you could start in a thousand different ways.

Comment: It really depends which domain you are targeting (cryptography, network, system, ...). You can already find [a few answers here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/it-security-learning-path)