# Careers in pentesting vs Development

Tags: career

I am working with a security organisation as a developer, recently in spare time, i found some vulnerabilities in our products, i reaction to this, there is a team being setup for pentesting, and they are asking if i am willing to join this new team.

I am confused on this, from career and growth perspective. By the way i am interested in development, i work on C/C++/Assembly windows, and personally i am also interested in hacking and finding new vulnerabilities as a hobby.

I need some suggestions, pros and cons, so that i can take some decision.

Comment: Having a developing background is a big pro. While performing a pentest you can see things from a developers perspective and thus know how they build things.

Another pro is that you can develop tools you use in order to perform these pentests (at least that's what I do) 

A con (or another pro, depends I guess) could be that you don't full time develop anymore.

In my opinion the better pentesters have a good developing background.

Good luck in making a decision.

Comment: For the people who are down voting, may i ask you the reason for the down vote.

Comment: you might be interested in http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3772/33 for context.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO:

As a pentester:

- You need to be updated every day, security field changes a lot, much
  more than others;
- If you like to break things and "hack the planet", you will be
  fascinated with this world;
- In times of Snowden, the security career is in evidence.

As a developer:

- You can create things and can see them "alive";
- Is easier to find help, because is a more common career;

I love the security field, but I can not say to you that it is better than others, depends on the company you work and on your commitment and passion.

Like @Jeroen - IT Nerdbox said:

> In my opinion the better pentesters have a good developing background.

I agree.